# Convert euro/cents to the lowest denomination of other currencies

Tags: node.js

I need to convert EURO/Cents to the lowest denomination currency for the other currencies, is there any package that does this ?

We are using this one to convert currencies [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecb-euro-exchange-rates), but it cant convert to lowest denomination.
For now I need solutions for this currencies  “AUD”, “CAD”, “DKK”, “EUR”, “GBP”, “NZD”, “SEK” and “USD”.

Is there any solution for this or I should grab from wikipedia exchanges for lowest denomination?

For example I need to convert 3.9 euro to pence or to lowest denomination of AUD

Problem is that I don't know what is equal main currency/ lowest denomination for all mentioned currencies

Comment: Consider giving some examples of inputs and expected outputs along with your attempt on solving this

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov update